Is integrity guaranteed by sending plain text with public key encrypted JWT and hash?
I am currently developing an RPC system that does not require message encryption, but does need client authentication and verification of message integrity.
I want the RPC server to minimize its state as much as possible, given that it is serverless and deployed globally. This means there are no shared secrets and no space for storing symmetric secrets through key exchange.

RPC server has private key and public key for asymmetric encryption, has private key to verify JWT.

RPC client can set password and login to get JWT outside this RPC system securely.

RPC client already has the encryption public key.

RPC client 's source code is public to any attacker.


Here is the plan:

Client send rpc packet:

(plain text, PublicKeyEncrypt( JWT ), PublicKeyEncrypt( hash( (plain text || JWT), "sha256")))


Server uses private key to decrypt the second part to get JWT, verify that message is sent by the specific client.
Server uses private key to decrypt the third part to get hash of plain text and JWT combination, ensure that plain text is not being modified by MITM.
Replay attack can be ignored in this question.

Is this system working as expected?
Edit:
I notice that there are some other ways:

(plain text, PublicKeyEncrypt( JWT ), hmac(plain text, JWT sign part))
(plain text, PublicKeyEncrypt( JWT || client random ), hmac(plain text, client random))

Is there any good one?
